# 'post_type_link' filter not working

Tags: permalinks, hooks

I know it should work fine, don't know if this is a recent bug or something. So, to confirm it, I installed a fresh wordpress using default theme. I made a small plugin like bellow:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Test
Plugin URI: http://www.something.com
Description: To test
Version: 1.0
Author: Yet another dev
Author URI: http://me.com
*/

add_filter('post_type_link', 'wpse33551_post_type_link', 1, 2);

function wpse33551_post_type_link( $link, $post = 0 ){
    return home_url( 'temp-tests/' . $post->ID );
}

add_action('init', 'sfsafsdsf_test');

function sfsafsdsf_test(){
    wp_die(get_permalink(1));
}
```

But for some reason it's still showing:

*http://example.com/2016/06/22/hello-world/*

Let me know if I'm wrong at something.

**Edit**

My concern is that above code should output this (or let me know if I'm wrong at something):

```
http://example.com/temp-tests/1
```

When I said "output", I mean the permalink for postID #1 should be like that.

**Edit 2**

No, this isn't a custom post type. I'm using default "post" for this.

Comment: What are you looking to accomplish, what is your issue

Comment: @PieterGoosen To put simple, I need to change permalink structure for specific post types

Comment: Please file an [edit] and add all relevant info in your question. Important info in comments is useless as many do not read comments

Comment: @PieterGoosen sorry about that. But I just need to know why 'post_type_link' isn't working even on a fresh installation. The posted code isn't my relevant code, I just came up with this to test it.

Comment: Is this a custom post type? Why not just modify the post_types rewrite rule - see [`register_post_types()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

Comment: @Howdy_McGee no, it's regular post. I would try to find a alternative but I'm wondering "why" post_type_link isn't working

Comment: @Rizwan, `get_permalink` is not calling `get_post_permalink` for built-in post types. Therefore the filtering never takes place the way you've set it up. Try using `get_post_permalink` instead, which is the function that `post_type_link` filters as [stated in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_type_link).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not a bug. As @LuisSanz pointed out, [`post_type_link`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L283) isn't used for the built-in `post` post type. It is used for custom post types only.

Skim through [`get_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/#source-code) function, you will find out that WordPress doesn't use `post_type_link` filter but uses [`post_link`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L224) filter. It means that you're using wrong filter.

Then, change `post_type_link` to `post_link` should fix the problem:

```
add_filter('post_link', 'wpse230567_filter_post_link', 1, 2);

function wpse230567_filter_post_link($link, $post = 0)
{
    return home_url('temp-tests/' . $post->ID);
}
```

Comment: `get_permalink` _does_ invoke the `post_type_link` filter, just not directly (and not for `post` post types). It returns `get_post_permalink` for anything that isn't a `post`, `page` or `attachment`, and _that_ return is filtered through `post_type_link`. So you can totally use `post_type_link` for **custom** post types and `post_type_link` should behave exactly as expected.

Comment: Also for the pages, the filter is `page_link`. Thank you for the pointer @janevu.