# When Attempting to Filter Plugin Generated Content Using Filter post_type_link, Permalinks Are Not Modified

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, filters

(My issue is not that described in ['post_type_link' filter not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/230567/post-type-link-filter-not-working). In that instance Rizwan was attempting to use post_type_link to filter posts, which are instead handled by post_link.)

In my case I'm trying to use post_type_link on a custom post type created by the [Liquid Messages plugin](https://github.com/LiquidChurch/lqd-messages). The post type is 'gc-sermons' and my code is as follows:

```
function lqd_message_link( $url, $post ) {
  if ( get_post_type( $post ) == 'gc-sermons' && isset( $wp_query->query_vars['messages-app-view'] ) ) {
    return add_query_arg( $_GET, $url );
    }
  return $url;
  }
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'lqd_message_link', 10, 2 );
```

If you go to a sermon series page like the below:

https://liquidchurch.com/sermon-series/divine-direction/messages-app-view/

And then mouse over one of the messages you see the link URL is:

https://liquidchurch.com/message/step-by-step

Whereas I'm looking for it to be:

https://liquidchurch.com/message/step-by-step/messages-app-view/

Any ideas?

Note: The CPT (gc-sermons) is set during its registration with ep_mask as EP_ALL.

Comment: It looks like those are archives, not single posts, so that's not the right filter. Other than that, it works as you'd expect. If you go to [an archive](https://liquidchurch.com/sermon-series/divine-direction/?test=123), the [links include the GET parameters](https://liquidchurch.com/message/step-by-step/?test=123).

Comment: What is the purpose of `add_query_arg` here? What the filter returns should be the same as the filters from your other questions.

Comment: Hi Milo! I was looking at this WP documentation which shows using add_query_arg:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_type_link/
YOU ROCK! I changed it to follow the form you provided me elsewhere and it works BEAUTIFULLY!

Comment: @Milo - So, one more little item. If a scroll to the bottom of the page I have navigation for "Older" and the link there appears as:
https://liquidchurch.com/messages/messages-app-view/page/2/
Which doesn't work. Is there a way for me to get this to work? Either by adding another endpoint or by somehow shifting the /messages-app-view to the end so it looks like:
https://liquidchurch.com/messages/page/2/messages-app-view/
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Milo provided the answer in the comments above. I'm recording for posterity sake. :)

I was using add_query_arg and should instead have used return $url, so the code above should have looked like:

```
function lqd_message_link( $url, $post ) {
   global $wp_query;
   if ( get_post_type( $post ) == 'gc-sermons' && isset( $wp_query->query_vars['messages-app-view'] ) ) {
   return $url . 'messages-app-view/';
}
   return $url;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'lqd_message_link', 10, 2);
```